# Stack Overflow OAuth - Python Social Auth

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-social-auth

Currently I am using the Python Social Auth module for authenticating users via OAuth service providers such as Google, Facebook, Github and Stack Overflow.

I have completed the process for fb, google and github, but I do not know how to do it for stackoverflow. The tutorial sites say that I need to  give the following in settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_STACKOVERFLOW_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_STACKOVERFLOW_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_STACKOVERFLOW_API_KEY = ''
```

What should be given in the template? For instance, I gave the following for google:

```
<a href = "{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}" > Google</a>
```

What is its equivalent for Stack Overflow? Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [psa django template example](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/examples/django_example/example/templates/home.html#L45). All you need to do is to pass correct stackoverflow's backend name. Also verify PSA version to ensure that local packet version support stackoverflow oauth.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
<a href = "{% url 'social:begin' 'stackoverflow' %}?next={{ request.path }}"> Stackoverflow</a></p>
```